# Parabola P has a focus at distance $1/|\sin\theta|+1/|\cos\theta|$ from the directrix, $\theta\in R$. The chord AB is normal to P at A, find min(AB)

Tags: geometry

> Parabola P has a focus at distance $1/|\sin\theta|+1/|\cos\theta|,\theta\in R$ from the directrix. The chord AB is normal to P at A, find min(AB)

A parabola is conic section with an eccentricity of 1 and/or the locus of a point which has the same distance from a fixed point (focus) and a fixed line (directrix)

We can find the length of the shortest normal chord in a standard parabola $y^2=4ax$. Points A,B are $(at^2,2at)$ and $(at_1^2,2at_1)$ where $t_1=-t-2/t$.

$AB=\sqrt{a^2(t^2-t_1^2)^2+4a^2(t-t_1)^2}$, and $min(AB)=2a\sqrt{27}$

Since the shortest distance between the focus and the directrix will lie along the common normal,

*distance of foci from vertex=distance of directrix from $=a=(|cosec\theta|+|sec\theta|)/2$*

The minimum value of a is coming as $\sqrt{2}$ from the above expression, which gives the minimum length of AB as 14.69  but the answer is 216. Where am I going wrong? Is the question wrong?

Comment: I agree $\min AB=\sqrt{216}$.  Maybe the answer is finding $\min AB^2$.

Comment: The equation of a parabola is $y^2=2px$ not $y^2=4px$ if p is the distance focus- directrix. See [here](http://www.nabla.hr/PC-Parabola1.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I too get $6\sqrt{6}$:**

$a\ge 2$

The length of the normal chord is given by $$(AB(t))^2=16a^2\frac{(1+t^2)^3}{t^4}$$
$$\frac{d(AB(t))^2}{dt}=32a^2\frac{t^6-3t^2-2}{t^5}=0 \implies t=\sqrt{2}$$
So $(AB)_{min}=AB(\sqrt{2})= 6\sqrt{6}.$

Comment: You may write your steps or tell your disagreement with my steps.

Comment: Yes. Thanks, But you could have just pointed my slip for $a\ge \sqrt{2}$